# How can I create two types of users in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm creating MVC5 app, and I'm already using ASP.NET Identity to create users. So, I already have the AspNetUsers table, and whenever user registers I get an entry there. I also have an Admin role, where I manually specify, which registered user is an admin. On the other hand, I also need to register Businesses, and much like normal Users, they will be able to log-in, register, and do some stuff. The point is that they will have both some similar and different fields with/from the normal users. For example, they will also have, e-mail address, password (which I want to be hashed like for normal users), e-mail confirmation, unique id etc. But they have different fields for more information, like their address, zip, country, category, etc. which normal users don't have. How can I achieve this in MVC?

Should I do something like the ApplicationUser class?

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
```

I mean, should I inherit my Business model from the IdendityUser? If yes, how will my model know which of the fields from IdentityUser to use and which not?

Here is my current Business model:

```
public class Business
{
    public int BusinessID { get; set; }

    public string BusinessName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Subcategory")]
    public int SubcategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Subcategory Subcategory { get; set; }

    public string BusinessAddress { get; set; }

    public string BusinessZip { get; set; }

    public string BusinessPhone { get; set; }

    public string BusinessDescription { get; set; }

    public string Facebook { get; set; }

    public string Twitter { get; set; }

    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

    public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }

    [Range(0.0, 5.0)]
    public double BusinessRating { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

So, apart from those fields, I want my table to include the stuff similar to AspNetUsers, like Email, EmailConfirmed, PasswordHash, SecurityStamp, etc.

**EDIT:**

Please note that some of my fields in the Business model are required. And also below you can find my ApplicationUser class.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple inheritance:

```
public class Business : ApplicationUser
{
    ...
}
```

You'll end up with a `Discriminator` column in your `AspNetUsers` table that will help Entity Framework identity which class it should instantiate for the row (`Business` or `ApplicationUser`). Then you can either just query as normal or if you only want one particular type or another, you can use `OfType<T>`:

```
var businessUsers = db.Users.OfType<Business>();
```

Note: By default, Entity Framework handles simple inheritance with a single table with a `Discriminator` column. For most cases this works just fine, but you must keep in mind that any property you add to subclasses of your base class, must be nullable. You cannot require something like a `DateTime` on `Business` to be required at the database-level, because then you could never save an `ApplicationUser`, which does not that property. However, this is only an issue at the database-level. You can still use view models to make a particular property on `Business` required from a front-end perspective.

Comment: If I use it like that, will it automatically get the other fields? Cause I don't want to get all the other fields from AspNetUsers, just some of them.

Comment: Yes, this is OOP 101, a subclass has all properties of the superclass. But, again, just because it's there, doesn't mean you actually have to *use* it. This is why view models are so important in a good application architecture. If you truly don't want certain properties to be present, you may consider creating classes like `BusinessUser : ApplicationUser` and `NormalUser : ApplicationUser`, which would allow you to only put the most basic set of properties that both types of users share on `ApplicationUser`, but remember that they'll all still go in the same table.

Comment: Quick question, I created two classes as these: Business : ApplicationUser, and User : ApplicationUser, then in my IdentityModels file, I have something like this: public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyProject.Models.Business> Businesses { get; set; }, and the same one for User model. Then I created a migration, but when I do Update-Database, I get an error message saying "Table 'aspnetusers' already exists". How can I solve this problem? Should delete all the tables in my database first and then do update-database?

Comment: You can try that. However, if you named the `DbSet` for `User` as `Users`, then you're going to run into issues with `IdentityDbContext`. It already implements a `Users` property for the user type specified, most likely `ApplicationUser`. You'll need to pick a unique name for your `User` set.

Comment: Okay, I will change the `DbSet` for that to `NormalUsers`, or I also need to change the model class' name?

Comment: No, the model class name is fine, technically, but it might get a little confusing retrieving `ApplicationUser`s from `Users` and `User`s from `NormalUsers`. In other words, if you keep the class name `User`, one might assume it could be retrieved from the `Users` set, which would be wrong. At least if you changed it to `NormalUser`, it would be a little more obvious that `NormalUsers` is the set for it.

Comment: Also, `db.Users.OfType<User>()` looks a little weird ;).

Comment: Anyway, I fixed my last problem. The point now is that in my tables, inside my aspnetusers table, I have all the fields of both Business and NormalUser models. And let's say when I create a new, I do something like this:
`var user = new NormalUser { FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);`
And it is as usal created in aspnetusers table, and Discriminator has value of NormalUser, but there is no separate table for NormalUser.