# ASP.Net MVC application with multiple users

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database, multiple-users

I am creating an ASP.Net MVC application related to design, buildings and etc. I need to have two types of users - Normal People and Companies. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627165/how-can-i-create-two-types-of-users-in-mvc5) I read how I can do it. I have created basic class `ApplicationUser`. The classes `PersonUser` and `CompanyUser` inherit this class and have some more properties. I am using MSSQL Database. I have thee following questions:

- **(My main question)** Should I create `DbSet<PersonUser>` and `DbSet<CompanyUser>` or I should create `DbSet<ApplicationUser>`?
- When I create database connections should the foreign key point to `PersonUser` and `CompanyUser` or to `ApplicationUser`?
- In controllers when I user `UserManager<TUser>` or `SignInManager<TUser>` depending on the user I need to use different properties. Do I have to have two `UserManager`s or I should parse like that every time `var user = (PersonUser) await this.userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);`?

Here are my classes:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IAuditInfo, IDeletableEntity
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        this.Roles = new HashSet<IdentityUserRole<string>>();
        this.Claims = new HashSet<IdentityUserClaim<string>>();
        this.Logins = new HashSet<IdentityUserLogin<string>>();

        this.Notifications = new HashSet<Notification>();
    }

    // Audit info
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    // Deletable entity
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<string>> Roles { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<string>> Claims { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin<string>> Logins { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public UserType UserType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class PersonUser : ApplicationUser
{
    public PersonUser() : base()
    {
        this.Bids = new HashSet<Bid>();
        this.Buildings = new HashSet<Building>();
    }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DesignerType DesignerType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bid> Bids { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class CompanyUser : ApplicationUser
{
    public CompanyUser() : base()
    {
    }

    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    // That is like Id of the company
    [Required]
    public string Bulstat { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two different scopes of problems related to having different "Types" of users in your application.

## Permissions / Authorization

This is the scope for what different types of Users are **allowed** to do. What endpoints are they allowed to call? What are they allowed to acces?

For this problem scope you want to use IdentityRoles in order to distinguish said users

## Database Relationships

This is the scope when the different types of Users will have genuinely distinct links in the database to different tables. For example for your SchoolDatabase, you may have `TeacherUsers` which have One to Many relationship with `StudentUsers`, and vise versa, but both types of users can login.

In this case you actually want to have different classes to distinguish them that inherit from a base User class.

Table links both types of users share, for example perhaps both a `Teacher` and a `Student` have a `Classroom` they belong to, you would put on the base class. Also chances are things like Password, Login, UserName, Email, etc would all go on the `BaseUser` class since everyone has such things.

Table links that are *unique`to one type of user would go on that users table. So if Teachers have a`Curriculum` then you would add a link between Teacher<->Curriculum, not BaseUser<->Curriculum, and if Students have Homework (but Teachers dont), then that link would be to the Student table specifically.

Comment: Thanks! Things are starting to get clear now. So as I understand I should create 2 tables in the database for both types of users?

Comment: Three tables likely, you also need some form of BaseUser I imagine, unless you dont have any added fields to link to all users aside from what `IdentityUser` already provides

Comment: What information will be stored in the `BaseUser` table? And what is the relation in the database between the `BaseUser` table and the other two tables? And how will both types of users will be able to register?

Comment: The relation is shared Id, BaseUser.Id would be same as UserTypeA.Id. UserTypeA should inherit from BaseUser to make this work in EF Core